# Hide/Show validation form issue

Tags: javascript, validation, hide, show

I want to make a simple validation form, but ive got a little error i cant fix. After I click on a login element I want a login_window appear(change from display:none to display:block) After that I want login and password inputs to show up. When I fill that up with anything else than "username" and "password" it should show me the alert message. Instead of that it keeps hiding the login_window even when there is no form(I just click submit and the login_window is hidden)

HTML:

```
<div id="login_window">
    <form name="login_form" onsubmit="return validate_login()" method="post">
        <label>Login</label>
        <input type="text" name="usr" placeholder="username"><br>
        <label>Sign In</label>
        <input type="text" name="psw" placeholder="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#login {
    position:absolute;
    width:65px;
    height:26px;
}


#login_window {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:460px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0  ;
    z-index:2;
}
```

JS:

```
var login = document.getElementById("login");
var login_window = document.getElementById("login_window");
login_window.style.display = "none";

login.addEventListener("click",function(){    
    login_window.style.display = "block";
});


function validate_login(){
    var un = document.login_form.usr.value;
    var pw = document.login_form.psw.value;                                           
    var username = "username";
    var password = "password";
    if((un == username) && (pw == password)){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("Login was unsuccesful, please enter the corrent name and password.");
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbf6zngo/)

Even though it works differently in the fiddle than it does in my browser, I have two questions.

1) Why is the login_window keeps hiding whenever I click submit?

2) Why isnt my validation form working?

Thank you

Comment: Answer to your 1st question: `login_window.style.display = "none";`

Comment: Just to point out... Never use javascript username/password validation on a *real world* application, as it can be read by anyone....

Comment: You have a timing issue: Uncaught ReferenceError: validate_login is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move your function to the body so it's available when called, it works.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbf6zngo/1/)

```
No wrap - in <body>
```

Also, please fix your [**comma splice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice). Why do programmers love so much to use them in alert messages? :-)

Comment: also, pardon me, but im still new with programmin, could you tell me how to do this in a browser?

Comment: It just means that you would add a `<script>` tag just before the closing `</body>` tag. The DOM elements need to be present before the script is loaded.